# Transition to a ViewController after FBLogin

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I've added the fbsdk to my iOS project successfully , but I'm having some trouble passing to another view controller after getting the user's info, here is my code:

```
 let parametri = ["fields":"email, first_name, last_name, gender, birthday, picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: parametri).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil){
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    // visualizza a schermo un avviso contenete l'errore nel fetch dell informazioni
    let avviso = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Si è verificato un errore con Facebook \n \(error.localizedDescription) \n , riprova più tardi.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    avviso.addAction(ok)
    self.presentViewController(avviso, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
    }
    else {

    print("scarico informazioni...")
        if let email = result["email"] as? String{
            print(email)
        self.utente.setObject(email, forKey: "user_email")
    }

    if let nome = result["first_name"] as? String{
        print(nome)
        self.utente.setObject(nome, forKey: "user_name")
    }
    if let cognome = result["last_name"] as? String{
        print(cognome)
        self.utente.setObject(cognome, forKey: "user_last_name")
    }
    if let sesso = result["gender"] as? String{
        print(sesso)
        if(sesso == "Male"){
        self.utente.setObject("Maschio", forKey: "user_gender")
    }
    else {
        self.utente.setObject("Femmina", forKey: "user_gender")
        }
    }

    if let compleanno = result["birthday"] as? String{
        print(compleanno)
        self.utente.setObject(compleanno, forKey: "user_birthday")
    }
    if let immagine = result["picture"] as? NSDictionary, data = immagine["data"] as? NSDictionary, url = data["url"] as? String  {
        print(url)
        self.utente.setObject(url, forKey: "user_profile_pic_url")
    }
}

    }

}// fine funzione

// - FB Delegate -


func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){
    if(error != nil){
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        // c'è un errore, presentare a schermo un avviso contenente il codice
        let avviso = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Si è verificato un errore con Facebook \n \(error.localizedDescription) \n  Riprova più tardi", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        avviso.addAction(ok)
        self.presentViewController(avviso, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    else{
        if (result.declinedPermissions.contains("email") || result.declinedPermissions.contains("user_birthday") || result.declinedPermissions.contains("user_hometown") ){
            print("non tutte le autorizzazioni sono state fornite ")

            let avviso = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Devi fornire tutte le autorizzazioni necessarie per poterti registrare con Facebook, per maggiori dettagli puoi visionare la nostra guida sulle autorizzazioni.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            func GuideSegue(alert:UIAlertAction!){
                // questa funzione mi porta alla pagina che spiega perchè ci servono le autorizzazioni
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("", sender: self)
            }
            let guida = UIAlertAction(title: "Guida alle Autorizzazioni", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: GuideSegue)
            func GrantPermission(alert:UIAlertAction!){
                FBPermissions()

            }

}
```

the classic "perform segue with identifier" doesn't work , any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you need to be very clear and specific on the problem that you want to solve.

Comment: I want to be able to go to another view controller after I fetched the user info, in this method:  else {

            // sono state fornite tutte le autorizzazioni

            print("utente collegato")
            FetchInfo()
        }

Comment: first of all why are you creating method `func GuideSegue(alert:UIAlertAction!)` and `GrantPermission(alert:UIAlertAction!)` inside of that last else

Comment: Guide Segue send you to a view controller where I explain why the application needs all the permissions, GrantPermission call the FBPermission method that asks back the missing permissions

Comment: declaration of any methods or functions should be outside, you would only need to call the function inside